# Prefetch Data in a specified interval nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, swr

I am currently working a project with next.js.
I got into the problem that I need to prefetch server side data an a specific interval e.g. once a day or every 3 hours.

The only ways for pre data fetching in the next.js documentation, is once on build time or on every request. With `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`

Is there a build in solution for interval based prefetching or is there a package that easily handles that for me?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the library https://github.com/zeit/swr

Here is a sample code which pull the data every 3 seconds.

```
import React from "react"
import useSWR, { SWRConfig } from 'swr'

function Dashboard () {
    const { data: events } = useSWR('/api/events')
    const { data: projects } = useSWR('/api/projects')
    const { data: user } = useSWR('/api/users', { refreshInterval: 0 }) // don't refresh
     return(
        <div>
          {/*Sample rendering */}
          {events && events.length > 0 ? (
            <div>
                  Show the event list or a chart.
              </div>
          ): (
            <div>No events</div>
          )}
      </div>
     )
}

export default function App () {
    return (
        <SWRConfig
            value={{
                refreshInterval: 3000,
                fetcher: (url, args) => fetch(url, args).then(res => res.json())
            }}
        >
            <Dashboard />
        </SWRConfig>
    )
}
```

On a side note: You should probably implement something like [PusherJS](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js) or similar to push the data into the browser. They have server libraries to push the data.